# Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning Beautiful Soup for Python and trying to parse a website "https://www.twitteraudit.com/". When I enter a twitter id in the search bar, it returns the results for some id in a fraction of seconds, but some id takes about a minute to process the data. In this case, how can I parse the HTML after it gets loaded or the result is done? And I tried to loop it, but it doesn't work that way. But what I figured was if I open a browser and load the web link and once its done it is storing the cache in the computer and the next time when I run for the same id it works perfectly.

Can anyone help me out with this? I appreciate the help. I attach the code below>>

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import re
from re import sub

def HTML(myURL):
    uClient = uReq(myURL)
    pageHTML = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    pageSoup = soup(pageHTML, "html.parser")
    return pageSoup

def fakecheck(usr):
    myURLfc = "https://www.twitteraudit.com/" + usr
    pgSoup = HTML(myURLfc)

    foll = pgSoup.findAll("div",{"class":"audit"})


    link = foll[0].div.a["href"]
    real = foll[0].findAll("span",{"class":"real number"})[0]["data-value"]
    fake = foll[0].findAll("span",{"class":"fake number"})[0]["data-value"]
    scr = foll[0].findAll("div",{"class":"score"})[0].div
    scoresent = scr["class"][1]
    score = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}',str(scr))[0]
    return [link, real, fake, scoresent, score]


lis = ["BarackObama","POTUS44","ObamaWhiteHouse","MichelleObama","ObamaFoundation","NSC44","ObamaNews","WhiteHouseCEQ44","IsThatBarrak","obama_barrak","theprezident","barrakubama","BarrakObama","banackkobama","YusssufferObama","barrakisdabomb_","BarrakObmma","fuzzyjellymasta","BarrakObama6","bannalover101","therealbarrak","ObamaBarrak666","barrak_obama"]

for u in lis:
    link, real, fake, scoresent, score = fakecheck(u)

    print ("link : " + link)
    print ("Real : " + real)
    print ("Fake : " + fake)
    print ("Result : " + scoresent)
    print ("Score : " + score)
    print ("=================")
```

Comment: Do some of the data not get received? I ran your code and got results for all 23 queries, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you for replying...just change the lis values with these values you might understand the situation.....       lis = ["TomCruise","TomCruiseFanCom","TomCruiseBRCom","TheAmyNicholson","TomCruiseIndo","MissionFilm","JackReacher","Not_TomCruise","Pompey_Dave","tomcruiseblog","cubanalaf","JustinMeliNY","rivergyllenhaal","eddiehamilton","TomCruiseActor"]

Comment: I see, yes you are correct, the script exits when the website reports there are no results. If you put the `for`-loop in a `while True:`-loop, it will pause at on the `ID` that doesn't have any results, at the same time, I go and request an audit from the page for that `ID`, and when the results are available, the script continues. Would that fix it?

Comment: So what I mean is it seems, unfortunately, the data never gets processed until you go to the page and manually request an audit of that Twitter `ID`, then, you're right, after about a minute, then the script *will* display the results. Does that sound acceptable?

Comment: ya, I agree with your statement but could you please tell a solution using a snippet so that i could be more clear of it. Thank you

Comment: Sure! I'm hesitant to post it as an answer, I'll put a code snippet on a link here: https://repl.it/HOw7/1 -- Everything before the `lis` list is the same as your code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is some of the Twitter ID's have not yet been audited, and so I was getting an `IndexError`. However, putting the call to `fakecheck(u)` in a `while True:` loop that catches that error will continually check the website until an audit has been performed on that ID.

I put this code after the `lis` definition:

```
def get_fake_check(n):
    return fakecheck(n)

for u in lis:
    while True:
        try:
            link, real, fake, scoresent, score = get_fake_check(u)
            break
        except:
            pass
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to automate the audit request on the website, but when a query is waiting, I manually clicked the "**Audit**" button on the website for that ID, and once the audit was completed, the script continued as usual until all ID audits were processed.